# Adding columns by merge - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have two data frames.
I want to create columns in df1 with the ID names from df2 and to assign into them the values of specific column in df2, but with considering the date.

Data illustration:

df1

```
ID  Date        X
A   07/16/2019  ..
A   07/19/2019  ..
B   07/28/2019  ..
```

df2

```
ID2 Day         Y   P
123 07/16/2019  ..  1.5
123 07/19/2019  ..  2.0
123 07/28/2019  ..  3.0
456 07/16/2019  ..  1.8
456 07/19/2019  ..  2.1
456 07/28/2019  ..  3.2
789 07/16/2019  ..  1.6
789 07/19/2019  ..  4.5
```

Expected result (df1):

```
ID  Date        X   123_P   456_P   789_P
A   07/16/2019  ..  1.5     1.8     1.6
A   07/19/2019  ..  2.0     2.1     4.5
B   07/28/2019  ..  3.0     3.2     NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Setup
import pandas as pd
col = ["ID2", "Day","P"]

data = [
(123, '07/16/2019', 1.5),
(123, '07/19/2019', 2.0),
(123, '07/28/2019', 3.0),
(456, '07/16/2019', 1.8),
(456, '07/19/2019', 2.1),
(456, '07/28/2019', 3.2),
(789, '07/16/2019', 1.6),
(789, '07/19/2019', 4.5),
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=col)

#Solution
piv_col = list(df2['ID2'].unique())
piv_col_renamed = [str(col) + '_P' for col in piv_col]
rename_dict = dict(zip(piv_col, piv_col_renamed))
df2 = df2.pivot(index='Day',values='P', columns='ID2').reset_index()
df2.rename(rename_dict,axis=1,inplace=True)

merged_df = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left',left_on='Date',right_on='Day')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two data frames:

```
raw_data1 = {'ID':  ['A', 'B', 'C'],
             'Date':['07/16/2019', '07/19/2019', '07/28/2019'],
             'X':   ['x', 'x', 'x']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data1)

raw_data2 = {'ID':   [123, 123, 123, 456, 456, 456, 789, 789],
             'Date': ['07/16/2019', '07/19/2019', '07/28/2019', '07/16/2019', 
                         '07/19/2019', '07/28/2019', '07/16/2019', '07/19/2019'],
             'P':    [1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 1.8, 2.1, 3.2, 1.6, 4.5]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data2)
```

I did the following steps:

```
## first make a new column that will end up being your column header
df2['colheader'] = df2['ID'].astype(str) + 'P'

# next 'pivot' over Date as index, colheader as columns and P as values
df2 = df2.pivot(index='Date',columns='colheader',values='P')

# next 'clean up' the dataset - this makes the headers easier to read
df2.columns.name = None
df2 = df2.reset_index()

# now merge with df1
df = df1.merge(df2,left_on='Date', right_on='Date')
df
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here is another way using `merge` and `unstack()`:

```
m=df.merge(df2,left_on='Date',right_on='Day').query('Date==Day').drop(['Day','Y'],1)
m=m.set_index(['ID','Date','X','ID2']).unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
```

---

```
m.columns=[f'{a}_{b}' for a,b in m.columns]
m=m.reset_index()
print(m)
```

---

```
  ID        Date   X  P_123  P_456  P_789
0  A  07/16/2019  ..    1.5    1.8    1.6
1  A  07/19/2019  ..    2.0    2.1    4.5
2  B  07/28/2019  ..    3.0    3.2    NaN
```